# Search dct and create new dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict that contains the following:

```
'Domain' : 'Google',
'Name' : 'Search',
'Position' : 'Top'

'Domain' : 'Amazon',
'Name' : 'Shopping',
'Position' : 'Top'

'Domain' : 'Google',
'Name' : 'Searching',
'Position' : 'Bottom'
```

I have a list of domains that I want to search and if my list contains a domain i want to remove it from the dict or create a new one with the filtered results

Desired output:

```
'Domain' : 'Amazon',
'Name' : 'Shopping',
'Position' : 'Top'
```

Code:

```
Exclusion = ['Google','Ebay']
for key, value in results.items()):
    for brand in Exclusion:
        if brand in Results['Domnain']:
            print("You have a match")
```

Comment: Please update your question with your real data. Its too difficult to work out what your program is doing without the data.

Comment: Can you please post how your dictionaries are formated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = [{'Domain' : 'Google',
'Name' : 'Search',
'Position' : 'Top'},

{'Domain' : 'Amazon',
'Name' : 'Shopping',
'Position' : 'Top'},

{'Domain' : 'Google',
'Name' : 'Searching',
'Position' : 'Bottom'}]

b = ['Google','Ebay']

[e for e in l if e['Domain'] not in b]
# Out[58]: [{'Domain': 'Amazon', 'Name': 'Shopping', 'Position': 'Top'}]
```